# Is it possible to auto translate words via scripting language?

Tags: scripting

Some words in String.log as following:

English

Home

Wait

Come

Back

And I want to translate words of String.log into French,like this:

Anglais

maison

attendez

venir

arrière

As we all know ,Google can do this,but if I have more then ten thousand words to translate,maybe do this via scripting language is more perfect.

Update Question：

I know about translation of a word depends heavily on context,so I just want to translate individual words, as @Gilles says,'it is a button for someone to click to switch to English'.

By the way,customers need confirm translation,so it is accepted translations barely readable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want to translate individual words or whole sentences? What are the parts that you want to translate and the parts that you don't? Give an example with a few lines of input and the corresponding output.

Comment: Note that automated translations are at best barely readable. Furthermore the translation of a word depends heavily on context. The translations you give here should probably be: *English* → *English* (if this is a button for someone to click to switch to English, put in in the target language, not in the ambient language; conversely, *Français* to switch from English to French); *Home* → *Maison*; *Wait* → *Attendre*; *Come* → *Venir* (? depends on the context); *Back* → *Retour* (if it's *back* as in e.g. *back button* in a broswer).

Comment: @ Gilles--See update question,plesae.

Comment: You haven't answered my questions.

Comment: @ Gilles--Could you tell me how to translate a word to other language via command?For example,if I want to translate words 'English' into French,run command:xxxx "English" ,then output Anglais.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/380847/is-it-possible-to-translate-words-via-terminal?